# How to set live background for an Activity?

Tags: android

I want to use multiple backgrounds for an Activity so that, while the application is running, the background automatically changes with a period of time. As in Instagram.

Comment: what you tried ? show your code...

Comment: you can use handler for performing operation in given time period @Bilal

Comment: setup your top level view with a "live" `Drawable` then

Comment: @NJ I just used android:background = "#FFFFFF"

Comment: @pskink can you explain briefly

Comment: @MithileshIzardar how to use handler for more then one background?

Comment: instead of `android:background`, call `setBackground(Drawable dr)` where `dr` is your "life" `Drawable` which "automatically changes with a period of time"

Comment: @pskink how to achieve it pragmatically?

Comment: how to call `View#setBackground`?

Comment: @pskink layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready);

Comment: where did i say `setBackgroundResource`?

Comment: @pskink In java file.

Comment: no,  i saId: `setBackground`

Comment: @pskink Sorry I am not getting you

Comment: are you aware of `View#setBackground` method? if so, just call it on your top level layout passing a :life" `Drawable`

Comment: @pskink No i am not aware of it, can you show me?